# casting size_t* to hsize_t*

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, integer

On my platform, `size_t` and HDF5's `hsize_t` are both unsigned 64bit integers, yet they are different C++ types (one is `unsigned long`, the other `unsigned long long`) and cannot be used interchangibly.

```
 using hsize_t = unsigned long long;
 void library_function(const hsize_t*);

 void client_code(std::vector<size_t> const&input)
 {
     library_function(input.data());     // error
 }
```

So my question: Is it in this situation required to convert

```
 void client_code(std::vector<size_t> const&input)
 {
     std::vector<hsize_t> tmp(input.size());
     std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), tmp.begin(),
                    [](size_t x) { return hsize_t(x); });
     library_function(tmp.data());
 }
```

or can I simply cast?

```
 void client_code(std::vector<size_t> const&input)
 {
     static_assert(sizeof(size_t)==sizeof(hsize_t),"!!");
     library_function(reinterpret_cast<const hsize_t*>(input.data()));     // correct?
 }
```

(this compiles, but is it guaranteed to work correctly?)

Comment: Even if it's technically UB, if `library_function()` is implemented in a separate translation unit, there is no way for the compiler do detect the strict aliasing violation (unless you enable link-time optimizations), so you can get away with using a `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing the value through the resulting pointer of the `reinterpret_cast` is an aliasing violation if the two types are indeed, up to cv-qualification, different non-`char` integer types that are not `unsigned`/`signed` versions of one another. Since you said that the two types here are `unsigned long` and `unsigned long long`, this applies to your case.

You cannot use it if you want to stay in the bounds of what the standard defines. There is also no way to type-pun one integer type to another, so you always need to copy (that may or may not be optimized out by the compiler).

---

You can usually still make this work in practice (even though it is undefined behavior according to the standard) by either setting some compiler flag like `-fno-strict-aliasing` which instructs the compiler to not optimize based on the guarantees given to it by the aliasing rule (which may come with worse performance) or by "hiding" the violating pointer access from the optimizer by putting it in a different translation unit (if link-time-optimization is not used). See also @HolyBlackCat's comment on the question.

Either is going to be unportable though. E.g. a different compiler (version) might do link-time optimization by default or not support the `-fno-strict-aliasing` or similar.

Comment: *if the two types are indeed different* are they? They are implemented using the same hardware instructions and the same alignment.

Comment: @Walter That doesn't matter. What is relevant is whether they are different types in the C++ type system. The aliasing rule allows the compiler to assume that two pointers of different type can never access the same memory location (with some exceptions), so that it can optimize based on that. Whether or not you are going to have a problem here depends on what the compiler is going to do, but it is technically undefined behavior according to the standard.

Comment: Even with the compiler flag `-fstrict-aliasing` (which switches on compiler optimasation based on the strict-aliasing rules), gcc-8 (according to its man page) will not break my code. Quoting from the man page: *In particular, an object of one type is assumed never to reside at the same address as an object of a different type, unless the types are almost the same.  For example, an "unsigned int" can alias an "int",*

Comment: @Walter There is an aliasing exception for `unsigned`/`signed` versions of the same type, see [\[basic.lval\]/11.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#basic.lval-11.2). It does not extend to different unsigned integer types. You can see all other exceptions in the standard paragraph that I linked. None of them applies here. I wasn't that clear about the exceptions in my answer.